# How does a compiler infer type for a parameterless method?

Tags: java, generics

From Effective Java :

> One noteworthy feature of generic methods is that you needn’t specify
>   the value of the type parameter explicitly as you must when invoking
>   generic con- structors. The compiler figures out the value of the type
>   parameters by examining the types of the method arguments.

So how does the compiler infer type in case of a method that takes no parameter ?

For example consider the following static factory method that creates a new HashMap every time it is called :

```
// Generic static factory method
public static <K,V> HashMap<K,V> newHashMap() {
return new HashMap<K,V>();
}
```

And when the method is called like :

```
Map<String,String> pair = newHashMap(); //it returns a Map<String,String>
```

and when it called like

```
Map<String, List<String>> anagrams =newHashMap(); // it returns a Map<String,List<String>
```

Comment: It can also infer the return type by the expectation at the call site, but only in limited cases: `String s = genericMethod();` where `<T> T genericMethod() {...}`.

Comment: @Geek, Do you have an example that you have in mind?

Comment: @KellyS.French see the edited question for an example

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Can you elaborate on your comment ..what are those specific cases ?

Comment: I just named the specific case: assigning the return value to a variable. It won't work in the position of a method argument. It *might* work in `return genericMethod();` but didn't try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It infers it based on the variable type that the return is assigned too.

```
public class GenericTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final GenericTest test = new GenericTest();
        String data = test.echo();
    }

    public <T> T echo() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In code example above, the compiler infers the generic parameter type based on the type of the `data` field, in this case `String`.

Comment: you meant to say that the type inference by the compiler is dependent on the return type coded by the programmer ? Where is the type safety then ?

Comment: When discussing method level generics the type safety is constrained to the scope of generic method body, the returned type, and subsequent operations on the returned type.

Comment: @Geek: what do you mean type safety? Your method is generic on T, so it is type safe for any T.

Comment: @Perception So what if we have multiple call to echo, each with different return type, say one with string and another with Integer?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has only a limited number of variables on which to infer types.  If a method takes no arguments, then the method can only be a simple override, since return values cannot be used to type methods, that leaves the name of the method itself. The compiler has to choose how far up the inheritance chain to select which parent/child class has the method to actually be called.